# What's the reason Rollup build Js into two files cjs and es

Tags: javascript, rollup

Recently I saw a package that has two built files.

```
index.es.js    
index.js
```

[image]

I am curious why there are two Js files.

When I import the package

```
import test from 'this-package';
```

which file will be used and how it determine which file to be imported?

Comment: Would be a better question if the title didn't include "cjs" which is not the name of any of the generated files (though the .js is indeed *common* js).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The file you get when doing a *default import* is documented in the `package.json` of that package (as in most npm packages) in the `"main"` property.

The reason you have two formats is that not every build environment supports ECMAScript Modules (import/export syntax, `.es.js`), e.g. node until version 11 didn't support `import` syntax, and thus, a fallback in the form of a [CommonJS](http://www.commonjs.org/) module is made available for your convenience.